# How to solve this expresion for the Beta factor?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I understand this one has no closed form solution

$$\sin(\beta-\theta)+\sin(\theta)e^{\beta/\omega\tau}=0$$

So besides to write it down in a software for numerical methods or symbolical algebra, how could it be at least aproximated the $\beta$ value?

Comment: I would convert this to complex coordinates, i.e., convert the exponential to trig functions or v.v. using Euler's formula

Comment: Are you concerned by all roots or just by the first one ?

Comment: I think the most practical is the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll presume $\theta$ and $\omega \tau$ are real constants with $\omega \tau > 0$ and $\sin(\theta) \ne 0$.  Note that the second term goes to $0$ as $\beta \to -\infty$, while the first oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ with period $2\pi$.  So as long as $n$ is sufficiently large, there will be a solution near
$\beta = \theta - n \pi$.  If we write $\beta = \theta - n\pi + x$,
the equation becomes
$$ (-1)^n \sin(x) + \sin(\theta) e^{(\theta - n\pi + x)/(\omega \tau)} = 0$$
and a good approximation will be 
$$ x \approx \frac{-\omega \tau \sin(\theta)}{(-1)^n \omega \tau \exp((\pi n - \theta)/(\omega \tau))+\sin(\theta)}$$